# create a Credential with access_token/refresh_token/expires_in parameters without the flow/installApp stuff

Tags: java, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-java-client

The quick start sample project is loading the *.json credential file, do the authorization flow, save the tokens in another file, and then use the token to create a credential. My goal is to do them in separate steps:

1. store the tokens in a DB after the exchange the authorization code for tokens
2. retrieve the tokens from DB
3. check the credential expiry and refresh token if needed and save it to DB again
4. create a credential object (without doing the flow/authorizationInstalledApp stuff)

So I tried the following to create the credential with the token related pramameters:

```
TokenResponse tokens = new TokenResponse();
String token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx$$$$$$$$$";
tokens.setAccessToken(token);
tokens.setTokenType("bearer");
tokens.setExpiresInSeconds(3500L);
Credential credential = new 
Credential(BearerToken.authorizationHeaderAccessMethod()).setFromTokenResponse(tokens);
```

The credential was created but the API call failed with:

> 401 Unauthorized {   "code" : 401,   "errors" : [ {
>       "domain" : "global",
>       "location" : "Authorization",
>       "locationType" : "header",
>       "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
>       "reason" : "authError"   } ],   "message" : "Invalid Credentials" }

I also tried another suggestion in the java doc:

```
public static Credential createCredentialWithRefreshToken(
      HttpTransport transport, JsonFactory jsonFactory, TokenResponse tokenResponse) {
    return new Credential.Builder(BearerToken.authorizationHeaderAccessMethod()).setTransport(
    transport)
    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
    .setTokenServerUrl(
        new GenericUrl("https://server.example.com/token"))
    .setClientAuthentication(new BasicAuthentication("s6BhdRkqt3", "7Fjfp0ZBr1KtDRbnfVdmIw"))
    .build()
    .setFromTokenResponse(tokenResponse);
 }
```

That also did not work for me. So my questions are:

1. can we just create a very simple credential object with access_token, refresh_token, expires?
2. why do we have to hook up with the GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow?
3. what's the minimum required parameters for a valid credential object based on Java client library (OAuth 2.0).

Thanks a lot for any ideas/input.

Comment: 1. yes 2. because the authorization runs through GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow you should be loading your stored credentials in that. 4. Easer to just save the entier token response to the database as a json object and feed that back to GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow

Comment: Could you please add the full code for the steps you're describing? Removing the personal information before of course. Also please add the code for the request you're making.

Comment: @DalmTo: thanks for your notes. I was able to save the json credential object to DB and retrieve/use it. But I was hoping to write java code based on the google client lib just to have a credential object without the flow/installed app code. That flow/installed app code is supposed to generate tokens. I will write code to use tokens separately (not in a same JVM) with a credential object created with tokens retrieved from DB. I can create credential but it is giving me that 401 error.

Comment: Let me make it very clear:  If Initialize a credential with just access/refresh tokens (without the flow code) it is giving me that 401 error upon 1st API call. So my goal: one process will do the flow and generate tokens. Another process will create a credential and use the credential to create gmail service object to make API calls. But the sample quick start code and all other examples are just put them together. So it would help if there is an easy to create a valid credential with tokens generated by another JVM (ignoring the flow stuff). hope it is very clear now.

Comment: I finally found a way to do the desired: if you have a refresh token, client_id, client_secret you can save it to a .json file and load it into GoogleCredential using fromStream:  GoogleCredential gc = GoogleCredential.fromStream(InputStream); fromStream will refresh for a new token in case it is already invalid. You can then use the credential object to make API calls. Tested and worked!